# Get user's last assignment (or re-assignment) to profile or permission set datetime

Tags: soql, data, schema

Is it possible? Let's say we have a lot of users, profiles and permsets. There is need to get last datetime when user was assigned to particular permset or profile using SOQL. Which fields could help?

Comment: Have you checked the `SystemModstamp` of [PermissionSetAssignnent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_PermissionSetAssignment.htm)?

Comment: Cool. But what about profiles?

Comment: The profiles are assigned to the User object and it does have a Last Modified Date. That could be a starting point.

Comment: it will work partially cause we can update any field

Answer (score 0):

The PermissionSetAssignment object lists the Permission Sets a user is assigned to. In addition, a PermissionSetAssignment exists for the user's profile. This design was meant to unify a user's permissions in to a single object so developer can easily determine what permissions a user has.

As such, you can query:

```
SELECT SystemModStamp, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE AssigneeId = <user-id>
```

And you'll get the last time the user's profile changed, as well as the last time an assignment was assigned to any user.

Comment: sfdcfox could you please explain more about profiles assigning? this moment is crucial for me now

Comment: @pincet It's just that. You assign your user a new Profile, they get a new ProfilePermissionSet that describes their new profile, and the old one is deleted.